# How do I remove hyphen from field column

Tags: python, arcgis-10.0

I want to use the Python field calculator to remove the hyphen from a field column. For example, I would like to parse out the hyphen from an entry like "123-45-6789" and read "123456789".

Comment: Why the down votes?

Answer (score 12):

Use the built-in [`str.replace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) method accessible on all string objects.

Make sure Python is checked in the Parser at the top

Put this in the Expression box (replacing "FieldName" with your own):

```
!FieldName!.replace("-","")
```

Answer (score 2):

The `sub` method in Python's regular expression module should do the trick.

```
import re
no_hyphens = re.sub('-','','123-45-6789')
```

This will replace any instance of a "-" with an empty string.